# Updates error message

Tags: updates

Receiving the following message. Any tips on this type of issue?  Thanks..

```
installArchives() failed: E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: regarding .../libgcc1_1%3a4.9.3-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb containing libgcc1:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
 libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9.3-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1:amd64
Error in function:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 depends on libgcc1; however:
  Package libgcc1 is not installed.
```

Comment: Configure the package 'multiarch-support'. Reinstall the packages 'debconf' and 'libgcc1'.  These are rare errors - any possible cause you suspect?

Comment: Receive this error when attempting to isntall libgcc1..

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9.3-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9.3-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: That's why you reinstall libgcc1 *last*. Look up 'pre-dependency' if you don't understand.

Comment: What is the best way to configure the package multiarch-support?   Thanks

Comment: `sudo apt configure <packagename>`. It may fail - if easy, the system would have done it already. You need the exact error message explaining why configuration fails.